# How to create a loop in smarty? Ex: for loop, while, do while and also switch statements

Tags: php, loops, foreach, smarty

I just want to ask how can I include a loop in smarty template? For example a simple for loop and a while loop. I read in the documents but I found nothing. I am a beginner in smarty. So if there's a link for the documentation for that please provide me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few builtin plugins:

- foreach http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl
- section http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.section.tpl

Comment: Any chance that you know how to make a loop without an array? like  regular for loop from 1-10. My smarty version doesn't support {for} for some reasons :(

Comment: On my second link, you can find a section based example: `{section name=foo start=10 loop=20 step=2}
  {$smarty.section.foo.index}
{/section}`